# Does $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^n} $ diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I think the following series is divergent as when l apply the divergence test, the limit approaches infinity. Is it correct ?

$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^n} $

Comment: No, the answer depends on the value of $x$.

Comment: @Bernard How do l find the values for which x converges,  it does converge for 1 as pointed below.

Comment: The simplest would be to use asymptotic analysis, and determine equivalents for the general term of the series, since the latter ultimately has a constant sign.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The summand is $x^n - x^{-n}$. If $|x|\neq 1$ this does not converge to zero, as one of the terms must become unbounded.

At $x=\pm 1$ the summand is identically zero. So the series converges when $x=\pm 1$. At other $x$ with $|x|=1$, the series fails the test for divergence as well.

Comment: How about $ |x| >0 $

Comment: either $|x|<1$ in which case $x^{-n}$ blows up or $|x|>1$ in which case $x^n$ blows up

Comment: Good point  lf $ f(x)= 1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}...$ then this series looks like $f(x)-f(1/x) $.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the value of $x$. For $x=\pm 1$, it obviously converges.

If $|x|\ne 1$, then either $0<|x|<1$ or $|x|>1$. Write
$$
a_n = (1-\frac{1}{x^n})(1+x^n) =: p_nq_n
$$

If $|x|>1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} p_n = 1$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n = \infty$.

If $0<|x|<1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n = 1$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty} |p_n| = \infty$.

Comment: i think you should be more careful in the case $|x|=1$; what if $x$ is complex?